# DVD driver stopped recognizing any discs

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, dvd, dell-studio, compact-disc

I have a Dell Studio 1537 with Windows 7 on it. My DVD driver stopped recognizing discs suddenly. It is not recognizing CDs, DVDs and not even the Windows 7 boot disc.

When I did `sfc /scannow` it keeps telling me that there are some corrupted files that it could not fix.

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this, but nothing seems to work. I have tried to

- uninstall and install the drive
- scan and fix the corrupted files with no luck and also
- repair the corrupted files through boot disc

But it did not recognize the disc. Windows is recognizing the drive, it is present in the device manager and says the device is working properly. When I insert a disc and try to open it from my computers it says "Insert a disc". I am not sure what else i can do to fix this.

Comment: Which "corrupted files" are you talking about?

Comment: You could try replacing the drive with a new one... it looks to me that this one went to retirement.

Comment: @slhck: When I did sfc /scannow it keeps telling me that there are some corrupted files that it could not fix.

Answer (score 1):

There is a laser inside of disc drives.  If it gets gummed up (i.e. fingerprints) it might cause some issues with disc reading.

I would recommend you use a lint-free cloth and **gently** wipe it off to see if it is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would second that answer.  If had an issue with DVD drives not recognizing disks and it was always hardware failure.